# Unrecognised selector crash when assigning delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using NSXMLParser to parse xml responses from a card processor. This code has been running ok for afew years until upgrading to xcode 9 and running on iOS11. Now I am getting an unrecognised selector, uncaught exception crash. I am running in xcode on an iPhone 7 device.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        DLog(@"received XML response: %@", response);
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(XMLRequestSucceeded:) withObject:response waitUntilDone:YES];
    } else {
       ......

(I get to here:)
-(void) XMLRequestSucceeded:(NSXMLParser *) response {
    response.delegate = self;   *** crashes here ****
    self.responseDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:20];
    [response parse];

    DLog(@"parser result %@", responseDict);
```

here is the header:

```
.....
#import <Foundation/NSXMLParser.h>

@protocol NSXMLParserDelegate;

@interface PaymentProcessor : NSObject  <NSXMLParserDelegate>  {  
}
.....
```

the error message:

> [NSHTTPURLResponse setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1c44356a0

Has there been a change in xcode 9 or iOS11 that could be causing this crash?  Thanks for you input.

Comment: None of this makes any sense. Why are you passing `response` (which is of type `NSURLResponse` to a method that takes a parameter of type `NSXMLParser`? Why are you even using `performSelector`? There are much better ways.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is the better way that you suggest?

Comment: Ignoring the use of `performSelector` for the moment, you need to figure out why you are passing a `NSURLResponse` to a method that expects a `NSXMLParser`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: There is a lot of code in the XMLrequestSucceded method and I did not want to clutter the NSURL session code

Comment: I am not sure how to use NSURLsession to produce an NSXMLParser response. I am a little new to this.

Comment: I believe that I have fixed the problem after you pointed me to the fact that I am passing a NSURLResponse to the method. I changed the performSelector call to send the responseObject (which is an NSXMLParser) to the success method. That seems to work. Why do you suppose that this has worked up until now?

Comment: There's no way the code you posted could ever have worked regardless of iOS or Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem (with the help of maddy's comments). I changed the parameter passed to XMLRequestSucceeded to be responseObject instead of response. I am now passing the NSXMLParser data to be parsed. Makes sense. I just don't know why this code worked succesfully for over 2 years now!

fix:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        DLog(@"received XML response: %@", response);
        [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] animated:YES];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(XMLRequestSucceeded:) withObject:responseObject waitUntilDone:YES];
    } else {
       ......
```